# How to make a pop up slider with Swiper js?

Tags: lightbox, swiper.js

I used a swiper.js slider and add a custome light box to it. when i click on the images from a slider they pop up like a lightbox and i cand navigate through the images but i have a problem i can not fix. when i click on one of the images in the swiper slider and the image pops up i use next or prev buttons to navigate through the images after i click on close button so i can exit the pop up window and go back to a normal Swiper slider it will take to the image that i calick on first not the image that i was seeing currently in the lightbox.

this is the code:

```
    var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
        slidesPerView: "auto",
        centeredSlides: true,
        spaceBetween: 30,
        pagination: {
            el: ".swiper-pagination",
            clickable: true,
        },
    });

    const lightboxTrigger = document.querySelectorAll(".lightbox-trigger");
    const lightbox = document.getElementById("lightbox");
    const lightboxImg = document.getElementById("lightbox-img");
    const closeBtn = document.getElementById("close");

    lightboxTrigger.forEach((trigger, index) => {
        trigger.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            lightboxImg.src = swiper.slides[index].querySelector("img").src;
            lightbox.style.display = "flex";
        });
    });

    closeBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        lightbox.style.display = "none";
    });

    lightbox.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        if (event.target === lightbox) {
            lightbox.style.display = "none";
        }
    });

    let currentImageIndex = -1;

    const prevBtn = document.getElementById("prev-btn");
    const nextBtn = document.getElementById("next-btn");

    prevBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        if (currentImageIndex > 0) {
            currentImageIndex--;
            lightboxImg.src = swiper.slides[currentImageIndex].querySelector("img").src;
        }
    });

    nextBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        if (currentImageIndex < lightboxTrigger.length - 1) {
            currentImageIndex++;
            lightboxImg.src = swiper.slides[currentImageIndex].querySelector("img").src;
        }
    });

    lightboxTrigger.forEach((trigger, index) => {
        trigger.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            currentImageIndex = index;
            lightboxImg.src = swiper.slides[currentImageIndex].querySelector("img").src;
            lightbox.style.display = "flex";

            lightboxTrigger.forEach(t => t.classList.remove("active"));
            trigger.classList.add("active");
        });
    });

    const closeLightbox = () => {
        lightbox.style.display = "none";
        currentImageIndex = -1; // Reset the current image index
    };

    closeBtn.addEventListener("click", closeLightbox);

    lightbox.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        if (event.target === lightbox) {
            closeLightbox();
        }
    });
```

the current image of the lightbox slider is not the current images of the Swiper slider when i exit the pop up window

Comment: You could just use Fancybox and Carousel from Fancyapps UI, they work perfectly together without writing any extra code.